How do I get browser pages when using Puppeteer.connect()?
I'm working on some automation with Puppeteer and I need to create the browser object by using Puppeteer.connect({ browserWSendpoint: endpoint }), rather than Puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).
The problem I'm having is that when I try to await browser.pages(), it seems like the promise never resolves and just hangs indefinitely, whereas if I were to create the browser object with Puppeteer.launch(), await browser.pages() returns basically immediately with an array of pages.
Below is the code that hangs, using Puppeteer.connect()
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function wsEndPoint() {
    // I have script running in the background that executes this terminal command
    // "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 "http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version" "http://localhost:3000/"
    // to open a chrome instance that allows me to connect to it via Puppeteer
    // and opens another tab that holds my React App that I use to interact with
    // my puppeteer instance

    return await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => res.webSocketDebuggerUrl)
}

async function myPuppeteerFunction() {
    console.log('program running')

    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: await wsEndPoint() })
    console.log('browser created')
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    console.log('page created')
    console.log(await browser.pages())

    // Doesn't log because await browser.pages() seems to not resolve
    console.log('This should log if the program does not hang')
}

myPuppeteerFunction()

Meanwhile, using Puppeteer.launch() does not hang
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function myPuppeteerFunction() {
    console.log('program running')

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    console.log('browser created')
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    console.log('page created')
    console.log(await browser.pages())

    // logs successfully
    console.log('This should log if the program does not hang')
}

myPuppeteerFunction()

I initially thought that my issue was that I'm using the 'puppeteer-extra' package and the 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth', but the same issue happens with the official 'puppeteer' package, just like I included in the example code.
Looking at the docs, it shows that both the .launch and .connect methods return a promise that resolves to a Browser object, so I'm confused as to why one works and the other does not.

await browser.pages() resolves fine for me on Puppeteer ^22.10.0 after connecting to a remote browser. What steps can I take to reproduce this? Note that there's an easier way to connect as shown here using browserURL.

@ggorlen This worked for me! Changing puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: await wsEndpoint() )) to puppeteer.connect({ browserURL: myURL }) resulted in no hanging when I executed await browser.pages()!
I am wondering how using the browserURL launch option versus the wsEndpoint launch option resulted in a different outcome, though.
To clarify, I am on Puppeteer ^22.12.0 and Node.js v20.0.0.
I'm not sure if you tested my exact code block, or if you just used the browserURL launch option, but the first example code block I provided was what was causing it to hang on my end.

But puppeteer.connect({}) won't connect to anything, right? I don't see how failing to connect solves the problem.

@ggorlen I accidentally pressed enter and added the comment when I was trying to start a new line. I have edited my comment to show the actual fix. I'm writing up an answer for the thread now.
The solution:
changing
puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: await wsEndpoint() })
to
puppeteer.connect({browserURL: "http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version" })
as you suggested.

Makes sense, thanks for clarifying. Both versions should work, though (I'm pretty sure browserURL is essentially a convenience property that does the fetch to get the WS endpoint for you under the hood), and if they don't work, then I would expect that the failure would manifest as an error thrown by connect(), not pages() hanging forever. So this seems fishy and unclear to me without some reproduction steps. It's cool you got it working, but if there's a bug in the library or something like that, it should be identified and fixed.

I would wager to say that a bug certainly exists. I'm running Chrome Version 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit). I believe my first example codeblock should be enough info to recreate the issue. To be more specific about the script mentioned in wsEndpoint, you can recreate the results of the script by creating a Chrome shortcut with the target set to "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 "http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version". I close all instances of Chrome, open the mentioned shortcut, then run my Puppeteer code, which results in hanging.

I'd open a ticket for Puppeteer if you have a repro, but it works fine for me on Ubuntu using your code with errors fixed (typo and some syntax issues, missing a call). There's probably some system-specific issue and I'd be surprised if this is generally reproducible.

Okay, will do. Thank you for the advice! I've been a professional full stack dev for a little over a year now, but coding for 3 years, so I was not quite sure what the proper procedure for something like this was. I appreciate you explaining the proper process to do things. And again, thank you so much for your help! You gave me the ability to continue making progress on my program.

Glad you're unblocked, but like I said, there's more work to be done if you want this to be helpful to the community beyond that. [edit] the post to be reproducible, with syntactically correct/runnable code and open a ticket with Puppeteer. They'll auto-validate that the code really does reproduce the issue, and if it doesn't, it'll likely be closed. Otherwise, this will die as some unknown issue between you and your particular system that nobody can reproduce.

Now I'm properly confused. I checked out my previous commit with the code that was causing the hang on my end and ran it without issue. I did close all of my Chrome browsers and then ran my script to open the remote debugging Chrome tab and my React App, but only after I found out your suggestion worked. It worked with your suggestion BEFORE I closed all my chrome browsers. I only closed all the browsers solely to properly document a step-by-step process to recreate the issue, so maybe something weird with my initial Chrome instance happened after it had been open for hours.

Yep--that's the importance of reproducibility. If you can't reproduce it any more, then there must have been some weird system state that caused the issue. Thanks for looking into it and fixing your code errors, and I'm curious to hear if you ever figure out what the problem was, or why one connect worked when the other more or less equivalent one didn't.

I'm definitely still curious as well. I honestly had no faith in using the alternate method you suggested fixing my issue, since I also figured it does the same thing that I was already doing, but I figured it was worth a shot since I hadn't tried it yet. If I run into the issue again, I'll do some more digging, try to record all actions I took to get to that point, try to figure out what the cause was in the first place and drop another comment here. I'll open a ticket as well. Should I leave this thread open, then?

Up to you, but the important thing is that you've provided the info and edit to clarify that it's probably not a code issue.

I discovered a way to reproduce the hanging issue while I was applying for jobs online today. Open a remote debugging instance of Chrome > go to Indeed.com > apply to any job that uses the Indeed application process (does not link away from Indeed) > get to either the "/intervention" or "/review" page of the application process. Puppeteer will now hang at await browser.connect() using either browserURL or browserWSEndpoint launch options. It is important to note that the Indeed application page shows "This page is protected by reCAPTCHA" and the submit page has a CloudFlare turnstile captcha.

Cool, can you provide a [mcve] of the code that does all that? If you have a reprex and feel it's genuinely a bug in the library, then post an issue for Puppeteer.

The bug does require some manual manipulation of the browser to create the environment that causes Puppeteer to hang. If Puppeteer is running / connected to the browser while you reach the "/review" page on Indeed, the captcha will just fail, solely because Puppeteer is running and connected to the browser, even if there is no automation running. It seems to be that when the captcha successfully verifies that you are a human, that's when the environment that causes the hanging issue emerges. It persists even after the Indeed pages are closed. Only fixable by closing all instances.

Is it okay to have only the code that checks to see if the browser will hang in the repo, and explain the process to manually get to the breaking environment? I'm not sure how I would programmatically successfully pass the captcha to get the browser into that breaking enviroment / state. I have a screen recording that I can upload to YouTube and include a link to in the repo as well.

I think if it's a genuine bug and takes some human steps to reproduce, as long as someone can reasonably do those steps, it's fine. It'll fail the automatic checker but a maintainer can still look at it.

I submitted an issue to Puppeteer. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/12715
Hopefully it gets some attention soon! I'm going to continue looking into it myself and hopefully come up with some more info. Thank you again for guiding me along the way! I'll continue to update here if I uncover more.

Edit: This solution MAY work for you. If it does not, you may be experiencing another similar issue that I ran into. Some captcha systems seem to make permanent changes to a browser instance that leaves it in a state that causes Puppeteer to hang whenever browser.pages(), browser.newPage() or Puppeteer.connect() are used. The only workaround that I have found so far is completely closing all browsers and restarting your remote debugging instance.
Solution provided by @ggorlen's comment:
I'm not sure what originally caused puppeteer to hang, but replacing the "browserWSEndpoint" launchOption
puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: await wsEndPoint()})
with the "browserURL" launchOption
puppeteer.connect({browserURL: "http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version" })
solved the hanging issue when awaiting the browser.pages() method.
I'm running Node v20.0.0 and this solution worked for me on Puppeteer ^22.12.0, as well as Puppeteer-extra ^3.3.6 with Puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth ^2.11.2
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function myPuppeteerFunction () {
    console.log("program running")

    // code that caused puppeteer to hang
    // const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: await wsEndPoint() })
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserURL: "http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version" })

    console.log("browser created")
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    console.log("page created")
    // does not hang anymore
    console.log(await browser.pages())

    // This will now log!
    console.log('This should log if the program does not hang')
}
myPuppeteerFunction()

EDIT: This code change did initially fix my issue, but I believe the actual issue was related to something on my own machine. Several hours after posting this solution, I attempted to recreate the issue so that I could open a ticket about the bug, but I was unable. Both my original codeblock and the solution codeblock work as expected, now. If you're experiencing this issue, try turning it off and on again. Close all your browsers, kill any node.js instances running your puppeteer program, and start from the beginning.
